# One to many relationship in springboot

Tags: java, sql, json, database

I have a file named data.sql which contains SQL queries 'INSERT INTO'.
I have table User which model is:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
// other fields
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "user")
@Column(name = "vacations")
private Set<Vacation> vacations = new HashSet<>();
```

And I have model Vacation where is:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "begin_date")
private LocalDateTime beginDateOfVacation;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "end_date")
private LocalDateTime endDateOfVacation;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "type")
private String typeOfVacation;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "reason")
private String reasonOfVacation;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

And in my data.sql I am trying to insert into vacation User with existing ID.
It "passing" threw compiler, but on localhost I can see only this:

> Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.springproject27.springproject.user.User["vacations"])

It is H2 Database Engine, the query which I try to pass is:

> INSERT INTO VACATION(ID,BEGIN_DATE,END_DATE,TYPE,REASON,USER_ID) VALUES
>      (22,'2012-09-17 18:47:52.69','2012-09-20 18:47:52.69','Unpaid leave','Sick',10);

Comment: sounds like a "SyntaxError" in your "JSON" "parse"ing.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with `Spring` nor `Sql` nor `database` of any kind.

Comment: So why when I comment query insert into vacation, I can see everything else ?

Comment: **update** problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see its happening because of JSON recursion when you are trying to serialize your data because of **bi-directional** relationship between `User` entity & `Vacation` entity. Preferred method to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` (if you are using Jackson 2.0+ version) to break the recursion during serialization.

**NOTE:** Other way to break the JSON recursion is using [JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) and [JsonManagedReference](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) in combiation. But I prefer `@JsonIgnoreProperties` due to no data loss during serialization.

> If you are using `Lombok`, only use @Getter & @Setter annotation not @ToString (or @Data which has @ToString included), as it will cause the same recursion issue.

```
class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    // other fields
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "user")
    @Column(name = "vacations")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
    private Set<Vacation> vacations = new HashSet<>();
}

class Vacation{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "begin_date")
    private LocalDateTime beginDateOfVacation;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDateTime endDateOfVacation;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String typeOfVacation;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reasonOfVacation;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("vacations")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: What are you using for setters & getters ? Are you using LOMBOK ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Lombok @Data

Comment: Yeah that creates the problem too. Only use `@Getter` & `@Setter` of lombok.

Comment: Holy crap :D Thanks bro !

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Lombok is not my favorite library, it has devils in it but can't avoid it makes the job easy.

Comment: Can you look at the comment below ?

Comment: @AmithKumar - I am also getting the same error though I'm not using lombok at all. In my case, this solution is not working

Comment: If you post a separate question with more details of your code, I might be able to assist. Without code reference, its hard to guess what could be causing failure in your case.