# SpringBoot persisting entities with relationships

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities like so

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascase=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private int car_id;

    private String color;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person owner;
}
```

So we have two entities with a relationship where a person can own many cars and each car can be owned by one person.

But this is attached to a restcontroller endpoint where it receives some json like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Joe",
  "cars": [
    {
      "car_id": 1,
      "color": "red",
    },
    {
      "car_id": 2,
      "color": "blue",
    }
  ]
}
```

So, a person with 2 cars. The endpoint is like

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/people"},
                method=RequestMethod.PUT,
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateApplication(@RequestBody Person personRequest) {
    Person person = personRepo.save(personRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When this endpoint receives the above json, I would expect that it saves the request object to the db including handling inserts/updates/deletes as necessary. However what I get is an error from the DB that the Car's owner cant be null. I see that it's not specified in the json but because of the mappings between the entities, I would expect that it knows the relationship. What am I missing?

Comment: You will have to include `@JsonIgnoreProperties` wherever there is a bi-directional relationship between entities, otherwise it goes into recursion, and that's what is happening here. Please see these [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273385/one-to-many-relationship-in-springboot/51278630?noredirect=1#comment89550150_51278630) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976307/jackson-json-two-way-object-reference/50976535#50976535).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like a infinite recursion.
A `Person` have **many** `Cars`.
A `Car` have **one** owner which is a `Person`.

Just a suggestion:

When you retrieve your entity, the Spring expect to have a `Person` (owner) inside your `Car` JSON structure and a list of `Car` inside of your `Person`. That could be a problem if you want to retrieve the data, since it will create a infinite recursion.
You need to add a fetch type to `LAZY` in order to prevent this recursion to happen.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Now, for your question, as I said, your `Car` need to have a `Person`, but in your request, you do not specify a `Person` (owner), so Spring don't know who the owner is. That's the main problem.

I would suggest you to update them separately:

```
@PutMapping("/people/{id}")
public ResponseEntity <?>handleUpdate(@PathVariable("id") Long personId, @RequestBody Person person) {
    Optional <Person> personOptional = personRepository.findById(personId);

    if (personOptional.isPresent()) {
        Person owner = personOptional.get();

        for (Car car: person.getCars()) {
            car.setOwner(owner);
        }

        carRepository.saveAll(person.getCars());

        person.setCars(null);
        person.setId(personId);
        personRepository.save(person);
    }

    return...;
}
```

In this example, I'm updating them separately, but in a single method.
Of course, you'll need to autowire both `PersonRepository` and `CarRepository`

**UPDATE:**

If you don't workaround someway, you'll need to have a JSON Request structure like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Joe",
  "cars": [
    {
      "car_id": 1,
      "color": "red",
      "owner" : 
      {
        "id": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "car_id": 2,
      "color": "blue",
      "owner" : 
      {
        "id": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not infinite, they are just mutually referential. It becomes an infinite problem when you try to serialize the relationship out to json but the real thing has a @JsonIgnoreProperties on it to block out the back references. The workaround that I put in place is to handle each sub object individually but that seems unnecessary when all the information needed is right there.

Comment: @MichaelB Understood. Actually, the workaround isn't unnecessary. You're not specifying who the `Person` is, so, when Spring deserialize your JSON to object, the `Car` owner is `null`, because there's no `"owner" : "...."` in your `Car`'s JSON structure. Anyway, hope this solves your problem

Comment: The "owner" on the car is the "person" who's "cars" list contains this car. In the DB this is only defined on one side of the relationship. (Car.person_id) In the json, it's defined once as well. There's no ambiguity.

Comment: @MichaelB Of course this is it. You know it and I know it, but Spring don't know it. When Spring deserialize, they are individual objects. That's why the `Car` owner goes as `null`. I've updated my answer with an observation